# Changing a parent in a nested-set with Sql

Tags: sql, nested-sets

I have a database structure that contains a parent/child hierarchy and am using a nested-set structure to represent it.
Each record has a parentkey and a lvalue and rvalue.
Inserting new children is easy. We can adjust all subsequent lvalues and rvalues easily.
But how do I re-adjust those values when I'm modifying the parent of a given node?
ie, I'm changing the parent a node belongs to.
Currently, I'm just recomputing the whole tree using a breadth-first traversal starting at the root nodes. 
Doing this in sql is time consuming (about 5min to process 50k records).

Is there any easier technique for updating those lvalue/rvalues?

I'm using Sql Server if that makes any difference.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently and ended up bring the whole thing into memory (C#) and doing the tree calculations there.  Or do a delete and insert instead of a re-parent.